# What did I have to do to install sdk for android developpement?

Tags: android

Did someone can tell me, step by step, how to install the SDK for developping android apps?

Comment: You'll find all you need to know [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: I already do all the step but something is missing and I don't know what is it... I suppose to be able to run the emulator and I can't do it. Can you help me please?

Comment: What errors did you get? You would get a better answer if you tell what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

The android website has this topic covered [Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) which is about as authoritative as you are going to get, along with a lot of other topics.

If you are having a specific problem you should list that.

Answer (score 0):

Android setup
->jdk1.6

-> Eclipse-jee-heliosSR1-win32.IDE(helios).
goto to help in Eclipse and install new software, where 
add this URL "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

->Plugins-ADT v12.0

->Android sdk 2.2,3.1(According to your requirements)"http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html"

configure AVD